# When you call a Web API method from jQuery, how jQuery knows what format to return?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

How does jQuery know what format to return? For example if you return IEnumerable, how does jQuery know to return array of objects in success callback? Or if JSON, same thing. Could you direct me to a link about it as I can't seem to find an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a header in the respons telling what mime-type the respons contains, e.g JSON:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

But there's no "type safety" between a client and a server in REST communication. The client must know how the Web API is constructed and what type of data it is returning.

If the respons is in JSON, jQuery is able to parse this into JavaScript object(s). If the respons is an array it is contained in brackets:

```
[object1 { prop1: "aaa"}, object2 { prop1: "bbb"}]
```

The ASP.NET Web API tries to send the response in a suitable way, and looks firstly at a header in the Request that tells the server what kind of Response the client can handle:

```
Accept: application/json
```

or:

```
Accept: application/xml
```

The ASP.NET Web API serialises the response in a suitable way, so an IEnumerable for instance becomes a JSON-array. You can also control this in your API, if you want to force the response to be in JSON.